# Can't boot after installing Ubuntu - dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I've just installed *Ubuntu 16.04* alongside Windows 10. After I completed the installation of Ubuntu and restarted, Windows boots as usual ... **just as if Ubuntu  wasn't installed at all.** 
I've tried the boot-repair method to reinstall GRUB, but it **didn't work !** What should I do ?

---

The hard drive is formatted with **GPT partition table** - the computer is running in **UEFI mode**.

Comment: Did you read Ubuntu's information about [UEFI booting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable Windows fast boot and hibernate.
Open command prompt as administrator and execute:

```
powercfg /h off
```

Then open Windows Control Panel -> Power Settings.
Enable show hidden settings and disable fast startup.

Shutdown the computer completely - do **not** reboot.
Boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu as the default OS.
Now you can select what to boot from GRUB menu.

Comment: Windows fast boot is already disabled .... when i boot into BIOS i don't find any thing .. just the windows boot manager besides the hard drive , CDrom .... etc

Comment: @ziademad : Please check the UEFI settings - there should be an Ubuntu entry ... maybe you have to set a password before to access these settings ... every BIOS is different, so I can't give exact instructions here.

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to the bios(usually by pressing f2 immediately after pushing the power button).

2.Go to the boot menu and set the boot mode to "UEFI OS & CSM OS".

Also disable secureboot/fastboot if it is enabled.